# TitleView of UITableViewController's UINavigationItem image not visible

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, xcode7.3, swift2, titleview

I am using Swift 2.3 in Xcode 7.3.  I have a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController.  I am trying to set the titleView of the navigation item in the navigationBar to create a button centered in the navigation bar.

The indexTextBut is a UIButton hooked up from the story board.  I have tried just creating a new button and it made no perceivable difference.  The way I am currently doing it the button is there as it has the behavior it should but no image.  I have tried just setting the title field as a string and even then I see nothing.  I set the right and left barButtonItems using:

```
navItem.setRightBarButtonItems(barButtonItems, animated: false)
navItemArray.append(navItemCatDet)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setItems(navItemArray, animated: false)
```

Here is my relevant code.  My big question is why can't I see the image of the button being set to the titleView.  It has preset behavior and when I click where it should be I get that behavior.  I've tried adjusting the frame of the UIButton and its UIImageView, and the size of the  UIImageView's image but have had no luck.  I included the line aobut tinting the background just incase it is related even though I have tried it with and without.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var indexTextBut: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var indexNavItemArray = [UINavigationItem]()
    var indexNavItem = UINavigationItem()

    indexNavItem.titleView = newButton
    indexNavItemArray.append(indexNavItem)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(netHex:0xe63246)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setItems(indexNavItemArray, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

> swift 3.0

```
var indexNavItemArray = [UINavigationItem]()
        var indexNavItem = UINavigationItem()

        indexNavItem.titleView = indexTextBut
        indexTextBut.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
        indexNavItemArray.append(indexNavItem)
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setItems(indexNavItemArray, animated: false)
```

> replace your code to above.

Comment: I am using Swift 2.  The code was easy to convert to Swift 2, only difference was "forState: .Normal" instead of "for: .normal".  That said it did not work, I still get no visual indication of the button or even the title text ("button").